# Excel for Mac alters document names after saving

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011

I have a 2012 non-Retina MacBook Pro with Excel 2011 for Mac version 14.6.3. Every time I save a document using the `Save As` command and save as a PDF document, Excel alters the name I entered as the document name; specifically it always adds the name "Invoice" to the document name.

For example if I click on `Save As` and enter *Document 1* as the name, the document will be saved as *Document 1 Invoice.pdf*

I do not remember changing any setting that would cause this kind of behaviour. What could be the cause and how do I change it?